# Axis2 WSDL2Java using a wsdl file written in .NET

Tags: c#, java, android, wsdl, axis

I have a webservice which I wrote in .NET. I also have an android applicaiton which shall communicate with this webservice. I want to auto generate classes instead of writing all the HTTP stuff to communicate with this webservice. In Visual Studio, you can just right click on `References` and `Add Service Reference`, and voila, the class which represents the webservice is generated automatically.

My webservice is hosted with `IIS`, and therefor the URL to this `WSDL` file is something like this

```
localhost/MyCoolWebService/Service.svc?wsdl
```

I found a tool which is called `axis2`, I installed this and tried to generate a java class out of this wsdl file. This process seemed to be straight forward, but I encountered a problem. After I completed the wizard and then hitting `Finish` to generate the class, I got an error:

```
An error occured while completing process
-java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

This doesn't make any sense, how come that people can't make any good error messages? Have anybody out there experice with creating java class out off `WSDL` files created in `C#.NET` ?

Comment: Do use the commandline(wsdl2java.bat) for generating the classes? The Exceptions is only one line? Can you show the wsdl? You could also use  jax-ws. An example can be found here: http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-wsimport-tool-example/

Comment: No I'm using the Eclipse plugin.